# How do I store and use 32 bit values in 16 bit mode

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers, real-mode, dword

Am I allowed to use E*X registers in 16 bit mode? If not how am I supposed to store and use 32 and 64 bit values (DWORDS and QWORDS). I know about using ax and dx together to store a 32 bit value, but how do I  address memory like that? I don't think I can do `push [ax dx]`, or can I?

Any information how do this is greatly appreciated, I looked online and it seems I am just to uneducated to figure it out because nobody seems to have the same question as I...

Comment: First of all, `[ax dx]` isn't a valid addressing mode, and 16-bit addressing modes can't use either AX or DX as base or index.  IDK what you wanted that to do, but maybe `push dx` ; `push ax` (two separate push instruction of register *values*, not memory source operands) is what you wanted to put 32-bit DX:AX on the stack.  Or `shl edx, 16` / `mov dx, ax` / `push edx`.  You can also merge with `or edx, eax` if you know the upper 16 bits of EAX are zero.

Comment: 64-bit operand-size for general-purpose integer registers (rax..rdi) requires 64-bit long mode.  Operand-size prefixes in 16-bit mode only get you 32-bit operand-size and/or address-size (introduced by 386)

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to use 32 bits registers/instructions in real mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917503/is-it-possible-to-use-32-bits-registers-instructions-in-real-mode)

The link above solved my question... I was just wording the issue wrongly in google.